# Pymongo tree structure getting node descendants

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I would like to port this [javascript](https://www.codementor.io/slavko/storing-tree-structures-in-mongodb-example-code-du107tk8d) example to Python.

Here is the original example which gets all node descendants:

```
var descendants=[]
var stack=[];
var item = db.categoriesPCO.findOne({_id:"Cell_Phones_and_Accessories"});
stack.push(item);
while (stack.length>0){
    var currentnode = stack.pop();
    var children = db.categoriesPCO.find({parent:currentnode._id});
    while(true === children.hasNext()) {
        var child = children.next();
        descendants.push(child._id);
        stack.push(child);
    }
}


descendants.join(",")
//Cell_Phones_and_Smartphones,Headsets,Batteries,Cables_And_Adapters,Nokia,Samsung,Apple,HTC,Vyacheslav
```

Python version is similiar to this:

```
def descendants():
    descendants = []
    stack = []

    item = db.electronics.find_one({'_id': "Cell_Phones_and_Accessories"})

    stack.append(item)

    while(len(stack) > 0):
        currentNode = stack.pop()

        children = db.electronics.find({'parent': currentNode["_id"] })

        while(next(children, None)):
            child = next(children, None)
            descendants.append(child['_id'])
            stack.append(child)

    print(descendants)
```

But as you'd see from the output some of the descendants are missing.

> ['Batteries', 'Cell_Phones_and_Smartphones', 'Samsung', 'HTC']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling next twice inside while loop, so the first next() is making you skip the items , try the following code

```
def descendants():
    descendants = []
    stack = []

    item = db.electronics.find_one({'_id': "Cell_Phones_and_Accessories"})

    stack.append(item)

    while(len(stack) > 0):
        currentNode = stack.pop()

        children = db.electronics.find({'parent': currentNode["_id"] })

        for child in children:
            descendants.append(child['_id'])
            stack.append(child)

    print(descendants)
```

The above is correction of your code, but you can reduce the database calls from the following code

```
def descendants():
    descendants = []
    stack = []

    item = db.electronics.find_one({'_id': "Cell_Phones_and_Accessories"})

    stack.append(item['_id'])

    while stack:

        children = db.electronics.find({'parent': {'$in':stack}})
        stack = []
        for child in children:
            descendants.append(child['_id'])
            stack.append(child['_id'])

    print(descendants)
```